# How to create a .BAT file opening program and preventing it from opening new windows?

Tags: batch-file, startup, batch-processing

So I am starting a consol program from .bat file. I want it to run as a process but not showing any windows. How to do such thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the start command with a '/B' option should do it ...

Windowless:

```
@echo off
start /B Myapp.exe
```

Minimized:

```
@echo off
start /MIN Myapp.exe
```

Comment: How to add params to that programms?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand what you mean: if you run a console program from a .bat/.cmd script, that program will use the *existing* console window, not create a new one.

I suspect what you're really asking is how to prevent Explorer from opening a console window for the .bat/.cmd script *itself*.  There's no built-in way to do that (although as amir75 suggested, you can mitigate it by running the script minimized; instead of running the script directly, create a shortcut to it and edit the shortcut's properties).

Alternatively, you can run your script through [the silentbatch program](http://www.taenarum.com/software/) that Paul Miner and I wrote.